# Pytube Error while trying to download a YouTube video

Tags: python, pytube

I'm trying to download a youtube video using python. However, i'm getting thrown an error even though my code is right according to many up-to-date videos.

I am using `Python 3.9.9` and `Pytube 15.0.0`

Here is my code:

```
from pytube import YouTube

video = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWXvSBHB210')
video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()`
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 405, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 311, in get_throttling_function_code
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 296, in get_throttling_function_name
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Tobias\Desktop\Exal\test01.py", line 4, in <module>
    video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 188, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 405, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 311, in get_throttling_function_code
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 296, in get_throttling_function_name
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple
```

This is the error I get specifically:
get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple

Comment: YouTube changes the structure of its metadata regularly.  Go check with the PyTube authors to see if they have an update.  You often have to fetch directly from their git page instead of pip.

Comment: It's a known bug: https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1699

Comment: Applying the Patch to the ciphey.py file from https://github.com/pytube/pytube/pull/1691/files   solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's a known bug and there is an issue opened for it , check at
https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1699

And also from the issue discussion we know that there is a pending PR with resolve , you can check ( and manually apply ) at
https://github.com/pytube/pytube/pull/1691/files